# No such file or directory - simple error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wrote my program and had it all working, I am starting to make changes to it so it is more efficient, I was told to use a class, I have never used one before, I have attempted to use a class, the program runs fine until you click go, I can see why you get this error and I think its to do with the two '' in line 11, but I'm not sure what I should put there instead.

```
#Imports
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

class MyFileManager(object):
    def __init__(self, filename='', save_filename=''):
        self.filename = filename
        self.save_filename = save_filename


    def save_users_list(self, list_name):
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
            users_list = [line.strip() for line in file.readLines()]

        with open(self.save_filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write('{} = {}'.format(list_name, str(users_list)))


    def get_filename(self):
        self.save_filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),
                                                        ("All files", "*.*")))


    def get_save_file(self):
        self.save_filename = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),
                                                          ("All files", "*.*")))

manager = MyFileManager()

#Window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Python List Maker")
window.geometry("300x170")

#Label
file_select_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Please select your file:")
file_select_label.pack()

#Button
filename_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Browse", command=manager.get_filename)
filename_button.pack()

#List Name
list_name_label = tkinter.Label(window,text="Please enter what you want to call the list:")
list_name_label.pack()
list_name = Entry(window)
list_name.pack()

#Save List
save_list_label = tkinter.Label(window,text="Please select where you want to save the list:")
save_list_label.pack()
save_filename_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Browse", command=manager.get_save_file)
save_filename_button.pack()

#Go
go_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Go!", command=lambda: manager.save_users_list(
                                                                    list_name.get()))
go_button.pack()

#Main Loop
window.mainloop()
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1490, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ashleymoakes/Desktop/Learning Python/WIP/List Maker/List Maker - Re-Write.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    list_name.get()))
  File "/home/ashleymoakes/Desktop/Learning Python/WIP/List Maker/List Maker - Re-Write.py", line 17, in save_users_list
    with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Also if it helps I am running Python 3.3

Comment: COuld you please provide the whole traceback of your error?

Comment: @wastl Of course, sorry I forgot to paste it, Its in my clipboard one second!

Comment: @wastl Just updated the question

Comment: Check `if self.filename != '':` before you save or read file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you never set the `self.filename` variable it stays empty and thus python is unable to find the file named `''`. I guess you'd have to change the `get_filename()` to the following:

```
def get_filename(self):
    self.filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Text files", "*.txt"),
                                                    ("All files", "*.*")))
         ^
     variable name changed
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, thought it was something simple, will accept the answer as soon as it lets me, thanks again